# When is the first quadrant of $\mathbb{R}^2$ covered by perturbations of rationally sloped lines?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the set of lines given by $y = rx$ for positive rational number $r$.  My question is as follows, does there exists some sufficiently small perturbation of every $r$, say $r+\epsilon$ where $r+\epsilon$ is no longer rational, such that all the lines of form $y = (r\pm\epsilon )x$ "cover" the first quadrant of $\mathbb{R}^2$?  If so, how large must this $\epsilon$ be? Is it sufficient for the $\epsilon$ to just be any  positive value?

I suppose a similar question would ask if it is possible to cover the real number line with the set of intervals $[r-\epsilon, r+\epsilon]$ for rational $r$?  Again, would the number line be "covered" by these intervals if $\epsilon$ was any positive value?

I apologize for the loose description and terminology, please comment if any of this is unclear and I will try to elucidate my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the arc $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1, x,y>0\}.$ For any $\epsilon,$ the set of lines $y=(r\pm \epsilon)x$ is countable. Hence the union of these lines intersected with $A$ is a countable set. Thus no countable collection of such lines can cover the first quadrant.

For the second question, note that $\mathbb R = \cup_{n=1}^\infty [-n,n].$

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if all the lines are instead of form $y = hx$ where $h \in [r-\epsilon, r+\epsilon]$ for rational $r$ and positive value $\epsilon$, then you have uncountably many such lines, and the space is covered?

Comment: Yes, that would do it. Note though that "uncountably" is a necessary condition  on the set of lines, but not sufficient.